# Burning tokens when it swaps in PancackeSwap

Tags: solidity, tokens, pancakeswap, burn, tokenomics

I`m trying to create token that burns some % of swap amount from liquidity pool every time user buy it.

I tried to implement it including `_burn` function to `_transfer` function overriding.

```
function _transfer(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 value
) internal override {
    uint256 toBurn = value * amountToBurn / 100;
    _burn(from, toBurn);
    super._transfer(from, to, value);
}
```

`amountToBurn` - is global variable that keeps precent of tokens i want to burn. For example, 5.
 I did it in this way for ability to change it using special function.

This is how burn function look like. As you can see, it`s default ERC20 burn function.

```
function _burn(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
    require(account != address(0), "ERC20: burn from the zero address");

    _beforeTokenTransfer(account, address(0), amount);

    uint256 accountBalance = _balances[account];
    require(accountBalance >= amount, "ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance");
    unchecked {
        _balances[account] = accountBalance - amount;
        _totalSupply -= amount;
    }

    emit Transfer(account, address(0), amount);

    _afterTokenTransfer(account, address(0), amount);
}
```

It works good when i do transfer between two adresses, but when i try to buy/sell it in [PancackeSwap(testnet)](https://pancake.kiemtienonline360.com) it returns error:

> *The transaction cannot succeed due to error: undefined. This is probably an issue with one of the tokens you are swapping.*

Maybe it should help you to answer:

1. It`s able to swap when `amountToBurn` is equal to 0
2. This is how burning look like when it was in transaction between 2 addresses(successful) `amountToBurn = 5`:
   **From** SenderAddress **to** 0x00000... **For** 50 TOKEN
   **From** SenderAddress **to** RecepientAddress **For** 1000 TOKEN
3. This is how burning look like when it was swaped `amountToBurn = 0`:
   **From** [PancackeRouter](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x9ac64cc6e4415144c455bd8e4837fea55603e5c3#code) **to** LiquidityPool **For** 0.001 BNB
   **From** LiquidityPool **to** 0x00000... **For** 0 TOKEN
   **From** LiquidityPool **to** RecepientAddress **For** 988.382... TOKEN
4. When swaped, [PancackeSwap(testnet)](https://pancake.kiemtienonline360.com) used `swapExactETHForTokens()` function `method:0x7ff36ab5`

Comment: Can you share your smart contract code for test it?

Comment: Sure, there is contract address(BSC Testnet): [0x1E710A58116d387269deda5D8297635632594dA6](https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x1e710a58116d387269deda5d8297635632594da6#code)

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious reason for the transfers to fail on pancake swap is due to the nature of how swaps happen in erc20 tokens , whenever a swap transaction happens we send token amount as a value to swap such as 100 and when our token contract burns 1 token on transfer pancake swap checks whether the amount is same as user requested to swap but instead of  100 Pancake receives 99 tokens so the transactiion is reverted.

**This is just my speculation, i'm gonna test it myself ping me if you have an update or want one.**